# Self-teaching physics recommendations?

Tags: education, mathematics

I've been very interested in mathematics for a while now and, after being inspired by reading Feynman's biography, would also like to learn about physics.  My mathematics background is fairly extensive.  I've taken courses through calc BC, the basics of multivariable calculus and a fair amount of linear algebra, with plans to take statistics next year.  My physics background is okay, in that I know what many of the individual symbols mean, but have never seen them put together in such a way that they yield all the wonderful results we see today.  Could anyone recommend a good place to start that makes use of this math background without being incomprehensible to my fledgeling physics knowledge and a freely available online textbook to accompany the former?  Thank you very much!

Comment: What sort of physics are you interested in? With a background in linear algebra, you should be okay for non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: I\m really interested in any sort of physics that deals with things that we can't see in everday life, particularly quantum mechanics.  Thanks for your help!